# Documentation on internal variables in ggplot, esp. PANEL

Tags: r, ggplot2

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600900/) uses a `PANEL` variable which seems to be internal to `ggplot`. But searching the [ggplot documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf) and also [Hadley Wickham's book](http://moderngraphics11.pbworks.com/f/ggplot2-Book09hWickham.pdf), I can find no reference to it at all. Is this documented anywhere?

Also, looking at the code for `stat_bin(...)`, there is evidently a vector `count` created (which contains the count of y for each unique x??). This is also accessible in `aes(...)` but, again, I can find no documentation.

**So my question** is: is there a place where all of these internal variables are documented, or must one just go to the code?

Comment: I really wouldn't advise using internal variables in that way - some things are not documented for a reason! (And may change in the future)

Comment: @hadley - Thank you for your comment. The reason I asked about PANEL is that its use appears to solve a major problem with `ggplot` - namely that aggregating functions do not respect the grouping implied in facets (see [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20058902/)). The usual response is to create auxiliary  tables which are grouped by the faceting variables, but the linked question above gets around that!

Comment: I would _strongly_ advise against it. Just do the aggregation outside of ggplot.

Answer (score 5):

There are some surprising gaps in the help pages for ggplot2 (and I would point also to the help page for ?layer to which many other pages refer users as a particularly egregious gap.) These "variables" have been around for years and like you I cannot find much in the online help or the package NEWS. SO's search facility is not much help because it strips off the leading and trailing dots and shows everything with "count". Only examples of their use can be found in cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf. Google is somewhat more helpful and the search string of:  ggplot2 ..counts.. delivers many informative hits. From context one forms that sense that these are not so much special variables as much as they are combined functions and program controls. These arguments implicitly transform the named arguments. They do seem to be implicitly mentioned in `?stat_bin {ggplot2}` albeit without the dots, and it appears that all four of these stat-variable-functions are calculated at the same time.

When I did a search in the pdf you linked to I found on pages 57-58  tables (#4.3,4.4) of "statistics" and "aesthetics" that you were asking for, but to my surprise it did not include `count`. Those tables are in section 4.7 that describes "stats".

(I have noticed improvement or the last couple of years in some of the pages to which these complaints were directed.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look over pp 57-58 of the book. Just to be clear, the `count` I'm referring to is not `..count..` (which is documented in various places), but the actual vector `count[]`, which is used in the answer to the linked question above.

Comment: That is probably a local reference to the dataframe constructed by `stat_bin`. At first I thought it was a call to the `count` function in `plyr'. (Bad design, IMO.)

Answer (score 2):

I think PANEL is a column in the component data of a plot. You get list of columns names:

```
names(ggplot_build(x)$data)
```

For the *count* and *frequency* variables, you can refer to Hadley book , page 69:

> Both the histogram and frequency polygon geom use stat_bin. This
>   statistic produces two output variables count and density. The count
>   is the default as it is most interpretable. The density is basically
>   the count divided by the total count, and is useful when you want to
>   compare the shape of the distributions, not the overall size. You will
>   often prefer this when comparing the distribution of subsets that have
>   different sizes.