# density histogram in ggplot2: label bar height

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have data that tells me how many minutes were required to solve a task:

```
dat = data.frame(a = c(5.5,7,4,20,4.75,6,5,8.5,10,10.5,13.5,14,11))
```

I plotted a density histogram of the data with the ggplot2 package:

```
p=ggplot(dat, aes(x=a)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),breaks = seq(4,20,by=2))+xlab("Required Solving Time")
```

Now I would like to add labels of the height of every density bar on top of it. I tried to reach this
by adding `+geom_text(label=..density..)`. 
This returns the error

> object '..density..' not found

however. Does anyone know what the input of the `geom_text()` function has
to be in my case to get those labels?

A solution without `geom_text()` is fine too but I would rather prefer
 to stay within the ggplot2 package.

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198896/how-to-get-data-labels-for-a-histogram-in-ggplot2/24199013#24199013

Comment: yeah I saw this answer when I searched stackoverflow but in my case it's a density histogram and not absolute frequency bars. I wasn't quite able to derive a solution to my problem from that answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `ggplot_build()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(a = c(5.5,7,4,20,4.75,6,5,8.5,10,10.5,13.5,14,11))
p=ggplot(dat, aes(x=a)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),breaks = seq(4,20,by=2))+xlab("Required Solving Time")

ggplot_build(p)$data
#[[1]]
#          y count  x xmin xmax    density ncount ndensity PANEL group ymin       ymax colour   fill size linetype alpha
#1 0.19230769     5  5    4    6 0.19230769    1.0     26.0     1    -1    0 0.19230769     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#2 0.03846154     1  7    6    8 0.03846154    0.2      5.2     1    -1    0 0.03846154     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#3 0.07692308     2  9    8   10 0.07692308    0.4     10.4     1    -1    0 0.07692308     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#4 0.07692308     2 11   10   12 0.07692308    0.4     10.4     1    -1    0 0.07692308     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#5 0.07692308     2 13   12   14 0.07692308    0.4     10.4     1    -1    0 0.07692308     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#6 0.00000000     0 15   14   16 0.00000000    0.0      0.0     1    -1    0 0.00000000     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#7 0.00000000     0 17   16   18 0.00000000    0.0      0.0     1    -1    0 0.00000000     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA
#8 0.03846154     1 19   18   20 0.03846154    0.2      5.2     1    -1    0 0.03846154     NA grey35  0.5        1    NA


p + geom_text(data = as.data.frame(ggplot_build(p)$data), 
              aes(x=x, y= density , label = round(density,2)), 
              nudge_y = 0.005)
```

Comment: In comments on [this question,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622332/documentation-on-internal-variables-in-ggplot-esp-panel) Hadley "strongly advise[s] against" using internal variables like PANEL, which I see as one of the columns in the ggplot_build() output. Are the other variables in ggpplot_build() here like density considered safer to use?

Comment: Or maybe ggplot_build(p)$data$PANEL is not the "internal" PANEL and is safe to use? [The docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.1.0/topics/print.ggplot?) seem to suggest that ggplot_build() should be as reliable as anything, since it's returned (invisibly) by print.ggplot. And Hadley's warning that I link to above is from 2013...

Answer (score 4):

You can label the bars using `stat_bin` with `geom="text"`. `stat_bin`calculates the counts, which we convert to densities using `..density..`, just as for `geom_histogram`. But by setting `geom="text"`, we display those density values as text. We also need to set the same `breaks` for `geom_histogram` and `stat_bin` so that the density values will match. I've placed the text labels in the middle of the bar by multiplying `..density..` by 0.5 in the label. However, you can of course adjust this however you please.

```
breaks = seq(4,20,by=2)  

ggplot(dat, aes(x=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks = breaks) + 
  stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=round(..density..,2), y=0.5*..density..), 
           breaks=breaks, colour="white") +
  xlab("Required Solving Time")
```

[image]

To get the labels just above the bars, you can use:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks = breaks) + 
  stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=round(..density..,2), y=..density..),
           breaks=breaks, vjust = -1) +
  xlab("Required Solving Time")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`..density..` comes from the stat, so you need to tell this layer to also use a binning statistic,

```
p + geom_text(aes(label=round(..density.., 2), y=..density..), 
              stat="bin", breaks = seq(4,20,by=2), 
              col="white", vjust=1)
```

[image]