# Calculate percentage for a column with certain condition of rows

Tags: r, frequency

I have a following dataframe:

```
 sleep health count prop
1     7   Good   100   NA
2     7 Normal    75   NA
3     7    Bad    25   NA
4     8   Good   125   NA
5     8 Normal    75   NA
6     8    Bad    25   NA
```

I want to fill the `prop` column with each percentage of `count` based on `sleep` group. For instance, the first 3 rows `prop` should be 0.5, 0.375, and 0.125 then the last 3 rows `prop` are 0.555, 0.333, and 0.111 respectively.

This can be done manually by separating the data frame by `sleep` first then use `prop.table(prop)` for each, but since there are numerous `sleep` group I can't find a succinct way to do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dplyr: finding percentage in a sub-group using group\_by and summarise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549731/dplyr-finding-percentage-in-a-sub-group-using-group-by-and-summarise) Or [Summarizing by subgroup percentage in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `R`, we can do this by dividing by the `sum` of 'count' after grouping by 'sleep'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(sleep) %>%
    mutate(prop = round(count/sum(count), 3))
#    sleep health count  prop
#    <int>  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1     7   Good   100 0.500
#2     7 Normal    75 0.375
#3     7    Bad    25 0.125
#4     8   Good   125 0.556
#5     8 Normal    75 0.333
#6     8    Bad    25 0.111
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$prop <- with(df1, ave(count, sleep, FUN=prop.table))
```