# Windowed (partitioned) % calculation using base R

Tags: r, partition

I have the dataframe below

```
df = data.frame(season = rep(seq(1,4),2)
                ,product = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4))
                ,revenue = 1:8
                )
```

I am looking to calculate each season's revenue as a % of total (inside each product's partition) such that the end table has the following column created

```
df$pc = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.19, 0.23, 0.27, 0.31)
```

I am aware this is achievable with packages such as `dplyr` as discussed here:
[Summarizing by subgroup percentage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r)
*However*, the challenge is to achieve this with base R functions or a combination of base R and user defined functions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `ave` ; `ave(df$revenue, df$product, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))`

Comment: @ Ronak Shah @akrun
Thank you both for your prompt contributions. Both solutions worked. I have now applied it to multiple variable partitions by
with(df, revenue/ave(revenue, list(season, new_variable), FUN = sum))

I would have done so in sqldf but your solutions are more compact. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by division

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(product) %>% 
  mutate(pc = round(revenue/sum(revenue), 2))
```

---

If we need `base R`, use `ave`

```
df$pc <- with(df, revenue/ave(revenue, product, FUN = sum))
```