# R: calculate rates within grouped values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say we have a dataframe looking like this one below:

```
month     issue          amount
Jan       withdrawal     250
Jan       delay          120
Jan       other          65
Feb       withdrawal     189
Feb       delay          122
Feb       other          89
```

My goal is to tweak this in order to get a dataframe giving me the percentages of each value in issue related to each month. Plainly speaking, my desired output should look like follows:

```
month     issue          rate
Jan       withdrawal     57.47
Jan       delay          27.59
Jan       other          14.94
Feb       withdrawal     47.25
Feb       delay          30.50
Feb       other          22.25
```

I've tried helping myself with dplyr but my attempts had all been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summarizing by subgroup percentage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "month     issue          amount
Jan       withdrawal     250
Jan       delay          120
Jan       other          65
Feb       withdrawal     189
Feb       delay          122
Feb       other          89", header = T)

df
#>   month      issue amount
#> 1   Jan withdrawal    250
#> 2   Jan      delay    120
#> 3   Jan      other     65
#> 4   Feb withdrawal    189
#> 5   Feb      delay    122
#> 6   Feb      other     89

df %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(rate = amount / sum(amount, na.rm = T) * 100)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   month [2]
#>   month issue      amount  rate
#>   <chr> <chr>       <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Jan   withdrawal    250  57.5
#> 2 Jan   delay         120  27.6
#> 3 Jan   other          65  14.9
#> 4 Feb   withdrawal    189  47.2
#> 5 Feb   delay         122  30.5
#> 6 Feb   other          89  22.2

df %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(rate = prop.table(amount) * 100)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   month [2]
#>   month issue      amount  rate
#>   <chr> <chr>       <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Jan   withdrawal    250  57.5
#> 2 Jan   delay         120  27.6
#> 3 Jan   other          65  14.9
#> 4 Feb   withdrawal    189  47.2
#> 5 Feb   delay         122  30.5
#> 6 Feb   other          89  22.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, rate := prop.table(amount) * 100, by = list(month)]
df
#>    month      issue amount     rate
#> 1:   Jan withdrawal    250 57.47126
#> 2:   Jan      delay    120 27.58621
#> 3:   Jan      other     65 14.94253
#> 4:   Feb withdrawal    189 47.25000
#> 5:   Feb      delay    122 30.50000
#> 6:   Feb      other     89 22.25000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r) . it might be what you're looking for. Code is pasted below for your convenience.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, group) %>% mutate(percent = value/sum(value))
```

In your case it would probably be something like :

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, month) %>% mutate(rate= amount/sum(amount))
```

Or alternatively :

```
group_by(df, month) %>% transmute(issue, rate= amount/sum(amount))
```