# Summarise and calculate percentage complete by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  sub = c(rep(1091, 3),
          rep(2091,4)),
  completed_sessions = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
)
```

I want to get the `percent_complete` by `sub`, with it calculated by num_complete/total_entries. `num_complete` is the count of '1's per `sub`, `total_entries` is the total number of observations of `PID`. How can I do this?

This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  sub = c(1091, 2091),
  num_complete = c(2,3),
  total_entries = c(3,4),
  percent_complete = c(66.67, 75.00)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summarizing by subgroup percentage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
example %>%
   summarise(num_complete = sum(completed_sessions), 
             total_entries = n(),
             percent_complete = num_complete/total_entries*100,
             .by = sub)

   sub num_complete total_entries percent_complete
1 1091            2             3         66.66667
2 2091            3             4         75.00000
```