# How to calculate percentage for rows based on sum of specific rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on the following data frame:

| LIBCOM | cluster | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aubervilliers | 1 | 60655 |
| Aubervilliers | 3 | 16876 |
| Aubervilliers | 4 | 11417 |
| Aulnay-sous-Bois | 1 | 2283 |
| Aulnay-sous-Bois | 2 | 43764 |
| Aulnay-sous-Bois | 3 | 30703 |
| Aulnay-sous-Bois | 4 | 10219 |
| Bobigny | 1 | 6789 |
| Bobigny | 2 | 3092 |
| Bobigny | 3 | 20502 |
| Bobigny | 4 | 23980 |

etc.

I am trying to calculate, for each city (LIBCOM) the percentage of inhabitants (pop) belonging to each cluster.

In other words, for example, for Aubervilliers, I'd like to calculate the total of inhabitants (60 655 + 16 876 + 11 417 = 88 948) and then find the percentage of inhabitants belonging to cluster 1 (60 655/88 948)*100 = 68 % (same for cluster 3 and 4, and same for each city).

I'm sure I can do it with dplyr but I've been struggling with several `group_by()`, `summarize()` and `mutate()` without managing.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(perc = pop / sum(pop), .by = LIBCOM)` (could add *100 if desired)- you can also see [Summarizing by subgroup percentage in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r) - if the suggested code or answers on that page dont work, edit your question to explain exactly what's not working with it. Good luck!

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you so much, and for the link to the other post as well. Have a nice day !